# Nonexistence of occupation density for differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Suppose there exists a continuous $L: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and Borel $B \subset \mathbb{R}$,

$$
m(f\vert_{(-\infty,t]}^{-1}(B)) = \int_B L(t,x) dx, \;\;\mbox{$m$ Lebesgue measure}.
$$

where $f\vert_{(-\infty,t]}$ is the restriction of $f$ to $(-\infty,t]$.

**Claim** $f$ is nowhere differentiable.

**Question** Proof of this claim?

Comment: @carmichael561 Good point, edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable everywhere.

By definition of $L(t,x)$, we have, for all $t$,
$$ 
L(t,x) 
= 
\frac{1}{2 \epsilon}\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \;\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} L(t,x) dx 
=
\frac{1}{2 \epsilon} \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \;m (f\vert_{[0,t]}^{-1} (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon )) 
$$

Now fix $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $t_0 = \inf_{s} \{f(s) = x_0\}$.
Then for all $t < t_0$, $L(t,x_0) = 0$.

We can choose $x_0$ so that, at $t_0$, there exists $C \neq 0$ such that, for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small,
$$
|t - t_0| \leq \epsilon \Rightarrow |f(t) - x_0| = |f(t) - f(t_0)| \leq C \epsilon.
$$

So, for all $\epsilon$ sufficiently small
$$
f\vert_{(-\infty, t_0]}^{-1} (x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon) \supset [t_0 - \frac{1}{C} \epsilon, t_0 + \frac{1}{C} \epsilon].
$$

Therefore

$$
L(t_0, x_0) \geq \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \cdot \frac{2}{C} \epsilon = \frac{1}{C} \neq 0.
$$

This shows $L(t, x_0)$ is not continuous in $t$.

**Example**

An example where such a occupation density exists (at a given point) can be constructed using the Cantor set. Each time a middle one-third, say $[\frac{p}{3^k}, \frac{p+1}{3^k}]$, is removed, define a function $f$ on $[0,1]$ by

$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases}
1 \;\; \mbox{on} \;\;[\frac{p}{3^k} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3^k}, \frac{p+1}{3^k} -  \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3^k}] \\
0 \;\; t = \frac{p}{3^k} \; \mbox{or} \; \frac{p+1}{3^k} \\
\mbox{affine on $[\frac{p}{3^k}, \frac{p}{3^k} + \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3^k}]$ and $[\frac{p+1}{3^k} -  \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{3^k}, \frac{p+1}{3^k}]$}
\end{cases}.
$$

Extend $f$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by, say, $f(t) = t$ on $(\infty, 0]$ and $f = 0$ on $[1,\infty)$.

For this $f$, the occupation time would have a density at, for example, $x=0$: Let $\epsilon > 0$, $f\vert_{(\infty, 0]}^{-1}[0, \epsilon)$ is (up to some multiple), the Lebesgue measure of the complement of the Cantor set in $[0, \epsilon)$.

An example where such occupation density exists everywhere is a sample path of Brownian motion, which exhibit such violent oscillations at every point.